# displaying sortable table for a custom query in an AdminTab instance

Tags: prestashop

I recently had to deal with a custom module written for prestashop 1.4, I have to display the

results in a std prestashop table (sortable, with filters) like the one for displaying orders

for example. I find that the official doc realy lacks a complete example for this case.

Any suggestion on how to proceed ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best way to use list in your module controller is to use HelperList class and is generateList function.

See blockreinsurance for sample

Best regards.